# OpenSSL: EVP_DigestSign() does't work on the Raspberry pi

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, openssl

I have trouble creating signatures with OpenSSL on a Raspberry Pi. RSA, ECDSA and EdDSA fail. Here is a small example:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

void main()
{
    // message to be sign
    std::string msg_str = "my messsage";
    std::vector<uint8_t> msg(msg_str.begin(), msg_str.end());

    // generate a key pair
    EVP_PKEY* key = EVP_PKEY_Q_keygen(nullptr, nullptr, "RSA", 2048);

    // signature
    std::vector<uint8_t> sig_out(1024); // reserve some memory

    // signing process
    EVP_MD_CTX* md_ctx(EVP_MD_CTX_new());
    size_t out_len = 0; // final signature length (calculated by openssl)

    if (EVP_DigestSignInit(md_ctx, nullptr, EVP_sha1(), nullptr, key) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "EVP_DigestSignInit error: " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << std::endl;
    }

    if (EVP_DigestSign(md_ctx, sig_out.data(), &out_len, msg.data(), msg.size()) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "EVP_DigestSign error: " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        sig_out.resize(out_len);
        std::cout << "signature length: " << sig_out .size() << "   data: " << std::endl;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < out_len; i++)
        {
            printf("%.2X ", sig_out[i]);

        }
    }

    EVP_PKEY_free(key);
    EVP_MD_CTX_free(md_ctx);
    return;
}
```

On my desktop PC all signatures work but not on the Raspberry Pi. Here is the screen output:

**Windows 10, AMD CPU, x64 system, OpenSSL 3.0.0:**

```
signature length: 256   data:
59 A9 45 F5 2B 97 51 F5 53 A8 AE 17 16 7A 26 28 
F5 68 3F 1F 3D B2 05 4F 0E 28 AF F2 F5 0E DA FF 
37 71 50 DD DA E1 DE F0 91 05 0A 07 79 30 00 03 
A4 1E F5 60 F5 7E 47 97 EF 88 9C 27 70 CE 64 63 
0B 6C 2E 50 7B D7 89 48 B6 73 44 AD 7A 02 EA 49 
BC D3 95 67 B8 E6 D9 E4 A1 4F 2B E8 F4 5C F8 73 
B5 53 B0 A5 FB BB 7A 81 1C 25 23 6F 30 D8 8F D8 
EC 9E 02 00 C2 0D 7C 9C 23 66 D7 44 62 FF 51 1A 
94 3F 6F FB D7 B2 C5 2B A4 03 09 E5 10 44 D4 AE 
A2 69 F3 EB 31 1B CB 2A 14 1D 76 CD 11 09 B9 76 
99 59 42 5A 74 3D 14 98 B7 87 FD 98 16 17 AC 9E 
DA 55 82 0B 93 3D 24 28 4F 09 EB EA AE 82 77 47 
B2 E2 C8 1E 62 FF E4 90 E6 18 E8 88 94 B4 F0 AF 
DF A2 2B D7 79 32 BD C5 0F B1 03 36 B6 D8 44 9A 
FA DB 02 EB 7D FE D5 D7 15 34 77 72 4D 4E 44 A8 
E7 DA D9 2B 49 80 43 58 1F AA F4 1D 27 80 1C EE
```

**Raspberry Pi, ARM CPU, Debian (bullseye), x64 system, OpenSSL 3.1.0:**

```
EVP_DigestSign error: error:1C8000B3:Provider routines::invalid signature size
```

does anyone have any idea what the problem may be? I am now a bit desperate.

best regards,
SBond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solved!**

this error occurs (only on ARM) when out_len is smaller than the final signature length. I need to change the code as follows:

from

```
if (EVP_DigestSign(md_ctx, sig_out.data(), &out_len, msg.data(), msg.size()) == 0)
{
    std::cout << "EVP_DigestSign error: " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << std::endl;
}
```

to

```
EVP_DigestSign(md_ctx, nullptr, &out_len, msg.data(), msg.size()); // calculates the final length (does not perform signature; therfore a fast process)
sig_out.resize(out_len);

if (EVP_DigestSign(md_ctx, sig_out.data(), &out_len, msg.data(), msg.size()) == 0)
{
    std::cout << "EVP_DigestSign error: " << ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL) << std::endl;
}
```

now I'm happy :)